# Output the values of a matrix by passing its pointer to a function

Tags: c, function

I am trying to send a pointer of a matrix to function for printing the values. However, my following code prints some long numbers so I assumed it prints the addresses instead! How can I print the value of the matrix after passing the pointer of it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

void printing(int *edge);
void main(){

int N=3;
int i,j;

int *edge[N]; 
for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
    *(edge+i) = (int *)malloc(N * sizeof(int));
}

srand(0);
for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < N; j++){
        if(i == j)
            *(*(edge+i)+j) = 0;
        else
            *(*(edge+i)+j) = 1; //rand() % 10;  
    }
}

printing(edge); // Pass the pointer of the matrix


}


void printing(int *edge){

int i,j; 
int N= 3;   
for( i = 0; i < N; i++){
   for(j = 0; j < N; j++){
       printf("%d \t", ((edge+i)+j)); // I think I have to do something in this line.
   }
       printf("\n");
}

}
```

Comment: I am sorry. I made a mistake.

Comment: Compile with [warnings](http://pastebin.com/RFuH5wAG) on.

Comment: That doesn't even compile.

Comment: There is no matrix (i.e. 2D array). And do not cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C!

Comment: Thank you guys for support .. I really appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter type of `printing` is incorrect.  It should be `int *edge[]`.  Then when you print, use `*(*(edge+i)+j)`, or better yet `edge[i][j]`.

The result:

```
void printing(int *edge[]){
    int i,j; 
    int N = 3;   
    for( i = 0; i < N; i++){
       for(j = 0; j < N; j++){
           printf("%d \t", edge[i][j]);
       }
       printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Also, be sure to `#include <stdlib.h>`, as it's needed for `malloc` and `srand`.

Comment: I would suggest avoiding the pointer dereference because without specifying the size of the data inside +1 might not move to the correct memory location depending on compiler implementation. Also for your code posted you forgot the [] in your function definition.

Comment: Thank you very much.. it fixed it

Comment: @MidoKammi Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.